# After loop all elements same

Tags: c#, arrays, element

I want to assign value to elements of my array. after running this, all elements of ListResults are same as last element of ListROI.

```
ListResults = new DataPoint[nROIrow];
DataPoint TempRes = new DataPoint();
System.Collections.ArrayList List = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < nROIrow; i++)
{
   TempRes.X = ListROI[i].X;
   TempRes.Y = ListROI[i].Y;
   TempRes.u = dispROIcorr[i, 0];
   TempRes.v = dispROIcorr[i, 1];

   ListResults[i] = TempRes;

   disp.Xpix = ListResults[i].X;
   disp.Ypix = ListResults[i].Y;
   disp.X = ListResults[i].X;
   disp.Y = ListResults[i].Y;
   disp.U = ListResults[i].u;
   disp.V = ListResults[i].v;

   List.Add(disp);
   bSAVE.Enabled = true;  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only create a `new DataPoint();` one time. So you end up with an array full of references to that same single instance.

The simple fix:

```
ListResults = new DataPoint[nROIrow];
//DataPoint TempRes = new DataPoint();
System.Collections.ArrayList List = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < nROIrow; i++)
{
   DataPoint TempRes = new DataPoint();
   ...

   ListResults[i] = TempRes;

   var disp = new ...
   disp.Xpix = ListResults[i].X;
   ....

   List.Add(disp);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you are reusing the `TempRes` variable. When you perform the "List.Add" you are just adding a reference to it, and all these references are (obviously) the same. You also modify it, so each identical reference logically points to the same identical data.

Instead, write:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList List = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < nROIrow; i++)
   {
     DataPoint TempRes = new DataPoint();
     ...
```

Note also that `ArrayList` is generally considered to be deprecated since .NET 2.0 and you should be using `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
disp = new ... // whatever
```

before assigning values to `disp[i].???`

actually what is happening is all the references in your `List` are referring to `disp` which is the single object that was created outside the for loop, hence all items in `List` are pointing to same `disp` object, hence same values.